# fontspec interfering with list of figures

Tags: xetex, fontspec

This script

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec} %requires XeLatex                                                                                                                                               
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures                                                                                                                                                                                              
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Histogram of results listed in Table \ref{tab:list}.}
  \label{fig:results}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{l l}
    A & B
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{table caption}
  \label{tab:list}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

is compiled well when I run `xelatex` thrice on it. A problem appears when I uncomment the line

`\usepackage{fontspec}`

Then the second compilation stops with an error:

```
    (./xe.lof
    ! Missing $ inserted.
    <inserted text> 
                    $
    l.1 ...rence `tab:list' on page 1 undefined}.}}{1}

What is the problem and how to solve it?
```

The contents of the `.log` file:

```
    This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex 2018.11.14)  17 NOV 2018 19:59
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**xetest.tex
(./xetest.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2018/02/21 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2018/02/21 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count87
\l_tmpa_int=\count88
\l_tmpb_int=\count89
\g_tmpa_int=\count90
\g_tmpb_int=\count91
\g__intarray_font_int=\count92
\g__prg_map_int=\count93
\c_log_iow=\count94
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count95
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count96
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count97
\l__iow_indent_int=\count98
\c_zero_dim=\dimen103
\c_max_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
\c_zero_skip=\skip43
\c_max_skip=\skip44
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip45
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip46
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip47
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip48
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
\l_keys_choice_int=\count99
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count100
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count101
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count102
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count103
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count104
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count105
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count106
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count107
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count108
\l__sort_length_int=\count109
\l__sort_min_int=\count110
\l__sort_top_int=\count111
\l__sort_max_int=\count112
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count113
\l__sort_block_int=\count114
\l__sort_begin_int=\count115
\l__sort_end_int=\count116
\l__sort_A_int=\count117
\l__sort_B_int=\count118
\l__sort_C_int=\count119
\l__tl_build_start_index_int=\count120
\l__tl_build_index_int=\count121
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count122
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count123
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count124
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count125
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count126
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count127
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count128
\l__regex_balance_int=\count129
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count130
\l__regex_mode_int=\count131
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count132
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count133
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count134
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count135
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count136
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count137
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count138
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count139
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count140
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count141
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count142
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count143
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count144
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count145
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count146
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count147
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count148
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count149
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count150
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count151
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count152
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count153
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count154
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count155
\l__regex_step_int=\count156
\l__regex_min_active_int=\count157
\l__regex_max_active_int=\count158
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count159
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count160
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count161
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count162
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count163
\g__regex_trace_regex_int=\count164
\c_empty_box=\box26
\l_tmpa_box=\box27
\l_tmpb_box=\box28
\g_tmpa_box=\box29
\g_tmpb_box=\box30
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen109
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen110
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen111
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen112
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen113
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen114
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen115
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen116
\l__box_internal_box=\box31
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box32
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen117
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen118
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen119
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen120
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen121
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen122
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen123
\c_empty_coffin=\box33
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box34
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box35
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box36
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box37
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box38
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box39
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box40
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen124
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen125
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen126
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen133
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def
File: l3xdvidpfmx.def 2017/03/18 v L3 Experimental driver: xdvipdfmx
\g__driver_image_int=\count165
\l__driver_tmp_box=\box41
))
Package: xparse 2018/02/21 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count166
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count167
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count168
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count169
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count170
)
Package: fontspec 2017/11/09 v2.6g Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
Package: fontspec-xetex 2017/11/09 v2.6g Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count171
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count172
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count173
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count174
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count175
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count176
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count177
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count178
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen134
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen135
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen136
\g__file_internal_ior=\read1

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def
File: tuenc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding TU on input line 82.
))
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \fontspec with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 542.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmainfont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 546.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setsansfont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 550.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmonofont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 554.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathrm with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 558.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setboldmathrm with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 562.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathsf with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 566.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathtt with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 570.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setromanfont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 574.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfamily with sig. 'mO{}mO{}' on line 578.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontface with sig. 'mO{}mO{}' on line 582.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \defaultfontfeatures with sig. 't+om' on line 586.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \addfontfeatures with sig. 'm' on line 590.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \addfontfeature with sig. 'm' on line 594.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 598.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newAATfeature with sig. 'mmmm' on line 602.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newopentypefeature with sig. 'mmm' on line 606.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newICUfeature with sig. 'mmm' on line 610.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 614.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeatureoption with sig. 'mmm' on line 618.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontscript with sig. 'mm' on line 622.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontlanguage with sig. 'mm' on line 626.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareFontsExtensions with sig. 'm' on line 630.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \IfFontFeatureActiveTF with sig. 'mmm' on line 634.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingCommand with sig. 'mO{}m' on line 3632.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingAccent with sig. 'mm' on line 3638.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingSymbol with sig. 'mm' on line 3644.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingComposite with sig. 'mmm' on line 3650.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingCompositeCommand with sig. 'mmm' on line 3656.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareUnicodeEncoding with sig. 'mm' on line 3681.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \UndeclareSymbol with sig. 'm' on line 3687.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \UndeclareAccent with sig. 'm' on line 3693.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \UndeclareCommand with sig. 'm' on line 3699.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \UndeclareComposite with sig. 'mm' on line 3706.
.................................................

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 3891.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 3896.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 3901.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 3906.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 3936.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \emph on input line 3961.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \- on input line 4015.
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/redefine-command"
. 
. Redefining command \oldstylenums with sig. 'm' on line 4110.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \liningnums with sig. 'm' on line 4114.
.................................................
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 99.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def
File: xetex.def 2017/06/24 v5.0h Graphics/color driver for xetex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen137
\Gin@req@width=\dimen138
)
(./xetest.aux)
\openout1 = `xetest.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
.................................................
. fontspec info: "setup-math"
. 
. Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid this).
.................................................
\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/lmr/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/bx/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/bx/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/lmr/bx/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/bx/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/bx/n on input line 4.
 (./xetest.lof
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.1 ...rence `tab:list' on page 1 undefined}.}}{1}

? x

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 10656 strings out of 493007
 244068 string characters out of 6136718
 309782 words of memory out of 5000000
 14653 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 530312 words of font info for 27 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 39i,1n,33p,10410b,233s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

The `.aux` file:

```
\relax
```

The contents of the `.lof` file are the following:

```
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces Histogram of results listed in Table \G@refundefinedtrue {\unhbox \voidb@x \hbox {\normalfont \int _zero:N \l __fontspec_em_int \int _zero:N \l __fontspec_strong_int \bfseries ??}}\GenericWarning { }{LaTeX Warning: Reference `tab:list' on page 1 undefined}.}}{1}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. The MWE compiles fine for me with `\usepackage{fontspec}` uncommented in both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. Can you check the `.aux` file for unexpected content and upload the full `.log` for the MWE run with errors?

Comment: @moewe, how do you compile the script?

Comment: You seem to have killed the compilation. At the error type x on your keyboard and then enter, so that the log can be correctly finished.

Comment: Beside this: protect the \ref in the \caption: `\protect\ref{tab:list}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer now I inserted the finished `.log` file

Comment: The relevant file is not the aux, but the lof as your error message shows. And if you look into it you will see that the reference in the caption broke. As I wrote: protect it (and delete the lof so that a sane one can be recreated).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, yes, adding `\protect` solved this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\ref` command is fragile, use `\protect`.

```
\caption{Histogram of results listed in Table \protect\ref{tab:list}.}
```

After making the fix, remove the `.aux` and `.lof` file. Such a removal is for the first time only.